# How to correctly write While loop headers?

Tags: java, while-loop

While loop events may be sentinel, flag, counter, or EOF. Using num as my variable, what is the correct way to write these. This is what i have so far, please correct if wrong.

1. Flag: `while (num <=5)`
2. sentinel: `while (num !=5)`
3. counter: `while (num=0; num < 5; num++).`
4. Im not sure how to write the header for the EOF.

Thank you for all the help. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure I understand what you mean.  Do you mean `while ( <your file reader>.hasNextLine())`?

Comment: i am trying to see how to write to just write the while loop header for each of the events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All IO calls will usually fail when there is not *and* will not be any more data to read. If you're using an `InputStream` to read into a byte buffer, your basic loop will look like:

```
InputStream in = …;
byte[] buffer = new byte[512];
int read = -1;
while ((read = stream.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    // process contents of buffer
}
```

Since the documentation for [`InputStream.read(byte[])`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#read%28byte%5B%5D%29) states:

> **Returns:**
>
> > the total number of bytes read into the buffer, or -1 if there is no more data because the end of the stream has been reached.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about your terminology, but 3 is wrong, and should be in a for(...) instead.

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(path);
String stuffRead = new String();

try
{
    while(true) {
        stuffRead += reader.readLine();
    }
}
catch(EOFException except){
    System.out.println("End of file reached");
}
catch(IOException except){

}
```